# Finding an expression for the Gauss Curvature in terms of $p, q$ and their derivatives

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Given $X_{u} • X_{v} = 0$ and an adapted frame $X_{u} = p \vec{e_{1}}$ and $X_{v} = q \vec{e_{2}}$ where $p$ and $q$ are positive functions on $U$.

- Find $\theta_{1}$, $\theta_{2}$, and then find an expression for $K$ in terms of $p$, $q$, and their derivatives.

Given $X_{u}$ and $X_{v}$ we can find the first fundamental form.

$$I = p^2 du^2 + q^2 dv^2$$

We have that $I = \theta_{1}^2 + \theta_{2}^2$

From $I$ we see that $\theta_{1} = p du$ and $\theta_{2} = qdv$

From here we can see that $d\theta_{1} = -p_{v} du \wedge dv$

Likewise, $d\theta_{2} = q_{u} du \wedge dv$

To find $K$ we first need to find $w_{12}$ and this is where I am running into trouble.

I have the following equations

$$d\theta_{1} + w_{12} \wedge \theta_{2} = 0$$
$$d\theta_{2} - w_{12} \wedge \theta_{1} = 0$$

Looking at the first equation we get

$$d\theta_{1} = -w_{12} \wedge \theta_{2}$$
$$-p_{v} du \wedge dv = -w_{12} \wedge q dv$$

This makes it look like $w_{12}$ has a $du$ piece.

Doing the same with the second equation

$$d\theta_{2} = w_{12} \wedge \theta_{1}$$
$$q_{u} du \wedge dv = w_{12} \wedge p du$$

This makes it look like $w_{12}$ has a $dv$ piece.

But $w_{12}$ cannot have both a $du$ and $dv$ piece. Then those wedges would be 0.

But if you actually try to figure out was $w_{12}$ is for each equation you get the following.

For equation 1: $w_{12} = \frac{p_{v}}{q} du$

For equation 2: $w_{12} = \frac{q_{u}}{p} dv$

So, they give different $w_{12}$. What does $w_{12} look like if it has both a du and dv piece? Any advice on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: First, here and in your other post, you keep getting the sign wrong when you differentiate ax$1$-form. Second, $\omega_{12}$ does have both $du$ and $dv$ terms. I have no idea why you say “then those wedges would be $0$.”

Comment: I mention those wedges because I have something like $w_{12} \wedge \theta_{1}$ if $\theta_{1}$ has a $du$ and so does $w_{12}$ then the wedge is 0 isn't it?

Comment: Which one form are you talking about with the wrong sign?

Comment: What is the derivative of the $1$-form $f(u,v)du$? ... For your second question, there are other terms, so what you say is very misleading: What is $(f\,du+g\,dv) +(h\,du+j\,dv)$? Yes, $du\wedge du = 0$, but so ... ?

Comment: The derivative of the one form would be $f(u,v)_{v} du \wedge dv$. One of the equations is  $d\theta_ {1} + w_{12} \wedge \theta_{2} = 0$ if say $w_{12} = a du \wedge dv$ and $\theta_{2} = b du$ then $w_{12} \wedge \theta_{2} = ab du \wedge dv \wedge du = -ab du \wedge du \wedge dv = 0$

Comment: You need to go back to the beginning and learn carefully. Even after I call attention to it, your derivative is wrong. And $\omega_{12}$ is a $1$-form, so this is nonsense.

Comment: How is it wrong? You take the $v$ derivative of the function and by doing so you pick up a $\wedge dv$. $W_{12}$ is a one form. That's what I've been saying all along. It cannot have a $du$ and a $dv$ piece. At least not wedged together because that would make it a two form. Unless you are meaning $dudv$ with no wedge.

Comment: The only way it would be different was if it became $dv \wedge du$ and then you can flip that with a negative sign. But that is just a matter of sign convention.

Comment: Okay looking through my lecture notes I see that I am incorrect. The terms that you are taking the derivative with respect to is the first term in the resulting wedge product. Therefore in your sample case it is $dv \wedge du$ and thus I would pick up a negative when flipping back to $du \wedge dv$.

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed the sign errors in my original post (thanks for pointing that out). I'm still confused as to what $w_{12}$ looks like? You said it has both $du$ and $dv$ pieces. Is it going to be something like your suggestion $(f du + g dv)$? I've never seen an example like this.

Comment: Looks like it should be $\frac{p_{v}}{q} du + \frac{q_{u}}{p} dv$ and then to find $dw_{12}$ we do the sum rule which will involve the quotient rule?